# How to get the variable name in a function call?

Tags: r, function

Sorry for my poor English but I can not think of a title that could concisely describe my problem, which is a little bit complicated than the title suggests.

Here is what I'd like to achieve:

In the global environment, one can get the name of a variable, say `xyz`, by calling `deparse(substitute(xyz))`. I need to use this at several places in my code so I decided to make it a function: `getVarName <- function(x){deparse(substitute(x))}`.

Then I write some function `myfunc` in which I need to call `getVarName`:

```
myfunc <- function(x){cat(getVarName(x))}
```

Now here is the problem: when I call `myfunc(y)`, instead of printing out `y`,  it still prints out `x`. I suspect it has something to do with the environment in which `substitute()` does the trick, but got no luck in that direction.

What do I have to do to make it right?

P.S. It'll be nice if some could edit the title with a better description of this question, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From what I saw while testing your code, it appears that `deparse(substitute(x))` will only print out the name of the variable which was immediately below it in the call stack.  In your example:

```
getVarName <- function(x){ deparse(substitute(x)) }
myfunc <- function(x){ cat(getVarName(x)) }
myfunc(y)
```

The call to `getVarName()` is processing a variable from `myfunc()` which was called `x`.  In effect, the variable `y` which you passed is not part of the call stack anymore.

**Solution:**

Just use `deparse(substitute(x))` directly in the function where you want to print the name of the variable.  It's concise, and you could justify *not* having a helper function as easily as having one.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Having this helper function is really just a personal preference. But still I am interested to know how this could be solved.

Comment: I am also interested whether @akrun will blow me out of the water with a brilliant response from left field.  And yes, the helper function would be great.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Just saw your comment.  I am not going to try anything here (+1) :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is typically the kind of functional programmming problem where you can use a decorator:

```
decorator = function(f)
{
     function(...)
     {
         print(as.list(match.call()[-1]))
         f(...)
     }
}

foo = function(x,y,z=2) paste0(x,y,z)
superFoo = decorator(foo)
```

Results:

```
> xx=34 
> superFoo('bigwhale',xx)
[[1]]
[1] "bigwhale"

[[2]]
xx

[1] "bigwhale342"
```

Comment: If I define `fun <- function(x) { foo(x) }` and then call `fun(xx)` it will output `x`, unless I'm mistaken here.

Comment: I edited my answer, decorator is clearly the way to go !

Comment: Thanks @ColonelBeauvel. However I'd like to wrap `as.list(match.call()[-1]))` in a helper function so that I can call it inside various functions. Your decorator does not seem to provide the flexibility that I need or maybe I totally missed your point. Would you please provide further insights on this?